# android listview - onfling inconsistent

Tags: android, listview, gesturedetector, onfling

Based on the code from [Android: How to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures), I've created the following `GestureDetector` for my `ListView` in order to handle swipes.

```
    public ListEntryViewHolder(View view) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(view.getContext(), new ListSwipeListener(view));
    }

    @OnTouch(R.id.rl_list_entry)
    boolean ListTouch(View ListEntry, MotionEvent event) {
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
```

The abstract `GestureDetector` looks like

```
public abstract class LeftRightSwipeListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 5;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 5;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        // Print Statement
        // Swipe Based Code that does some math and calls onSwipeRight() and onSwipeLeft()
    }

    public abstract void onSwipeRight();
    public abstract void onSwipeLeft();
}
```

Using the `print` statement within `OnFling`, I've found that `onFling` is being called in a very inconsistent manner; only about half of my swipes trigger the function to be called. If and when the function is called, it's able to distinguish between `onSwipeRight()` and `onSwipeLeft()` just fine. Disabling long clicks seemed to help a little, but it's unclear why `onFling` only triggers from time to time, perhaps the `MotionEvents` are getting consumed somewhere?